# Loop through columns in foreach php

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to loop through the columns of a row in a foreach loop to create a new array for each row.

```
$e = 1;
$columns = array('colname1', 'colname2', 'colname3', 'colname4','colname5');
foreach ($variable as $row) {
  for ($i=1; $i < 5;)
  {
      $new_array[$i] = (
      array(
          'id' => NULL,
          'order_line_id' => $order_line_id,
          'size' => $e,
          'qty' => $row->$columns[$i] //error is here
          )
      );
      $i++;
      $blank_detail[$i] = (
      array(
          'id' => NULL,
          'order_line_id' => $order_line_id,
          'size' => $e."-",
          'qty' => $row->$columns[$i] //error is here
          )
      );
      $e++;
  };
}
```

Is there a better / more efficient way to do this or is it just a syntax error?

Comment: Where does $variable get set and can you show the output from a var_dump() or print_r() of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using an array as a [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), so you need to change this line :

```
'qty' => $row->$columns[$i]
```

to

```
'qty' => $row->{$columns[$i]}
```

also there are a lot of changes in handling the indirect variables between PHP7 and PHP5, [check it out](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.indirect).

> Indirect access to variables, properties, and methods **will now be
>   evaluated strictly in left-to-right order**, as opposed to the previous
>   mix of special cases. The table below shows how the order of
>   evaluation has changed.

So if you are using this syntax `'qty' => $row->$columns[$i]` in PHP5 this will mean that you PHP will interpret your code and get the `$i` index from the `$column` array, while in PHP7 the interpreter will interpret your code and get the `$i` index from the `$row->$columns` array which will throw an error because :
1 - `$columns` is an array and you are trying to access illegal index type so to speak.
2 - even if `$columns` is a valid index type ( string ) this index does not have the `$i`th element.

---

also I'm pretty sure that you can make a use of [array_combine](http://php.net/array_combine) instead of perform two nested loops